# Window installer return 3 Install initialize .. failed

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I just made an installer and it has nothing. But when I install it it gives below error:

```
Action start 18:37:31: InstallInitialize.
Action ended 18:37:31: InstallInitialize. Return value 3.
Action ended 18:37:31: INSTALL. Return value 3.
MSI (s) (48:D4) [18:37:31:786]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: ASM MT CPC 1.0.0.0. Product Version: 1.0.0.0. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: ASM. Installation success or error status: 1603.
```

It shows that InstallInitialize return **value 3**. What's the issue or what i am missing?

Comment: Is this one of those empty MSI packages wrapping a custom action? Search the whole MSI log for "value 3". [Explanation here](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/).

Comment: There is no custom actions. I just create new installer and there is nothing except install location.

Comment: Just add a component and install a dummy file. And set the Manufacturer attribute. [Sample minimal project here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972615/129130).

Comment: Yes it worked. I have been working on MSI since couple of months and whenever i stuck or did some mistake you helped. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem. Good that it worked.

Comment: On the database level, you don't need any dummy files, just a dummy component and a dummy feature linked to it.