# Wix Minimal UI doesnt show up

Tags: visual-studio-2017, wix

I'm trying to create a simple installer with Wix, but the Windows Installer doesn't show up. So I've tried the basics, which is:

1. Add Wix v3 Setup project
2. Fill in Manufacturer
3. Build and open the .msi
   It shows a popup with "Title" Preparing to install
4. Add reference WixUIExtension
5. Add `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />` so should it should show the UI
6. Build and open the .msi
   Nothing appears and I have to kill the Windows Installer via Task Manager

What could be wrong?

**Answer to Stein:**

Prevalence: Do other MSI files work without issues?

- The built-in VS Setup Wizard builds a .msi which works.

Timeout: How long do you wait for the MSI to initialize?

- 10 minutes

Source: Maybe post your whole source.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="MinimalTester" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MinimalTester" UpgradeCode="795294d8-45b1-4110-a80c-4a593e86bc68">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
  <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
  <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="TestLicenseAgreement.rtf" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MinimalTester.Installer" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MinimalTester" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Feature="ProductFeature">
        <File Source="C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.exe" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Logging: Always make a log file for your installation session to debug.

```
    === Verbose logging started: 10/12/2018  08:43:43  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.10011.00  Calling process: C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (EC:A0) [08:43:43:124]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (EC:A0) [08:43:43:125]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:158]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:159]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:159]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: TestApp.Installer.msi
       ******* Action: 
       ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:166]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:227]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:228]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: Verifying package --> 'C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.Installer.msi' against software restriction policy
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:229]: Note: 1: 2262 2: DigitalSignature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:229]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.Installer.msi is not digitally signed
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:231]: SOFTWARE RESTRICTION POLICY: C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.Installer.msi is permitted to run at the 'unrestricted' authorization level.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:237]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:237]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:241]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:241]: Original package ==> C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.Installer.msi
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:241]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.Installer.msi
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:243]: APPCOMPAT: Compatibility mode property overrides found.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:244]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{A401E2B5-DBD1-41AC-8F84-BC9EAF39E728}'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:244]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:253]: MSCOREE not loaded loading copy from system32
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:256]: Machine policy value 'TransformsSecure' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:256]: User policy value 'TransformsAtSource' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:256]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: MsiFileHash 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:256]: Machine policy value 'DisablePatch' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:256]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownPatch' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Machine policy value 'DisableMsi' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Running product '{A401E2B5-DBD1-41AC-8F84-BC9EAF39E728}' with user privileges: It's not assigned.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Machine policy value 'DisableLUAPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Machine policy value 'DisableFlyWeightPatching' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{A401E2B5-DBD1-41AC-8F84-BC9EAF39E728}'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Transforms are not secure.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiLogFileLocation property. Its value is 'C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\Your.log'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Command Line: CURRENTDIRECTORY=C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug CLIENTUILEVEL=0 CLIENTPROCESSID=18924 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackageCode property. Its value is '{60067773-7475-4FB5-B5D0-26E6934E64E2}'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Product Code passed to Engine.Initialize:           ''
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Product Code from property table before transforms: '{A401E2B5-DBD1-41AC-8F84-BC9EAF39E728}'
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Product Code from property table after transforms:  '{A401E2B5-DBD1-41AC-8F84-BC9EAF39E728}'
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Product not registered: beginning first-time install
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ProductState property. Its value is '-1'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Entering CMsiConfigurationManager::SetLastUsedSource.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: Adding new sources is allowed.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:257]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding PackagecodeChanging property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: Package name extracted from package path: 'TestApp.Installer.msi'
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: Package to be registered: 'TestApp.Installer.msi'
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: Note: 1: 2262 2: AdminProperties 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: Running product '{A401E2B5-DBD1-41AC-8F84-BC9EAF39E728}' with user privileges: It's not assigned.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CURRENTDIRECTORY property. Its value is 'C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTUILEVEL property. Its value is '0'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding CLIENTPROCESSID property. Its value is '18924'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding MsiSystemRebootPending property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: TRANSFORMS property is now: 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:258]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionDatabase property. Its value is '200'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:259]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:259]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\Favorites
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:259]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:259]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\Documents
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:259]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:260]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:260]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:260]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:260]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:260]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Local
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:260]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\Pictures
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:261]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:261]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:261]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:261]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:261]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Public\Desktop
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:262]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:262]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:262]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:262]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:263]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\Users\Colin\Desktop
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:263]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:264]: SHELL32::SHGetFolderPath returned: C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:265]: Note: 1: 2898 2: MS Sans Serif 3: MS Sans Serif 4: 0 5: 16 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: MSI_LUA: Setting AdminUser property to 1 because this is the client or the user has already permitted elevation
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding AdminUser property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding Privileged property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MS Setup (ACME)\User Info 3: 2 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DATABASE property. Its value is 'C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.Installer.msi'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding OriginalDatabase property. Its value is 'C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\TestApp.Installer.msi'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: Machine policy value 'MsiDisableEmbeddedUI' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is 'C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\'.
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:274]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is 'C:\Source\TestApp\bin\Debug\'.
MSI (c) (EC:A0) [08:43:43:275]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VersionHandler property. Its value is '5.00'.
=== Logging started: 10/12/2018  08:43:43 ===
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:292]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: PatchPackage 
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:292]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:292]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (c) (EC:7C) [08:43:43:292]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UILevel property. Its value is '5'.
```

Comment: Did you try to disable your anti-virus or any other security software before installing? Do a full malware scan first please! And update the virus definitions first.

Comment: You are not wrapping this in a Burn bundle are you? (`setup.exe`)

Comment: No virus or malware found and I have no problems at all with my machine, I'm not using Virtual Machines, just everything local. I'm not wrapping it in a bundle, the output is file.msi and file.wixpdb.

Comment: System reboot solved the problem...

Comment: Great, thanks for letting us all know (for the next person who sees the problem).

Comment: Updated my answer and added a "deployment mnemonic" for others who see similar problems. Not everyone comes back with the solution to the problem, thanks for doing so. Then we can try to make answers useful for the next guy.

Comment: And ourselves once we have forgotten all about it :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***System Reboot***: In this case a simple reboot solved the problem - which is great news.
>
> ***Speculation***: One could speculate as to why, and maybe it had to do with ***PendingFileRenames*** (file and folder names waiting to be
>   changed) or some lock in Windows Updates that affected the System
>   Restore point creation? Doesn't sound too likely. Just speculation.
>
> ***A Deployment Mnemonic***: To think about this - if you see the problem - a deployment mnemonic: **`What is locking`** (in use),
>   **`what is blocking`** (permissions), **`what is corrupt`** (disk, malware, configs, encryption), **`what are unexpected system states`**
>   (disk space, time & date settings, language, licensing, windows patch
>   state, path too long, PendingFileRenames, etc...), **`what are incompatible products`**
>   (things that can't co-exist), **`what is unreachable or misconfigured`** (what points to erroneous locations and resources: network server names,
>   disk paths, URLs, databases, services, UAT environments, PROD environments, etc...) and last but not least: **`what is missing`** (runtime, resource image, settings file, etc...)? [Launch debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530377/129130).

---

And **the older answer**. Leaving in to perhaps spark ideas:

- ***Prevalence***: Do other MSI files work without issues?
- ***Timeout***: How long do you wait for the MSI to initialize?

  - ***Initialization & System Restore***: The Windows Installer engine may create a system restore point before the GUI is shown. This can be quite slow, and your setup could appear to hang.
- ***Source***: Maybe post your whole source.
- ***Logging***: [Always make a log file for your installation session to debug](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm).

Sounds like you don't need it, but here is a: [Sample, minimal MSI compile with WiX Votive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970743/wix-installer-msi-not-installing-the-winform-app-created-with-visual-studio-2017/47972615#47972615).

Gut feel is that there might be an AppSearch in this dialog set that I am unaware of. Maybe try to have a look at [the sources yourself first](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/wix3111/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib) (**`WixUI_Minimal.wxs`** et al). Any other issues with your machine? **Virtual**? Up to date with **hotfixes**? **Malware** checked? **Disk space**? **Event logs**?