# WiX v3 Setup Project, Unable to uninstall via Apps & Features

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is causing this odd issue.

So I've created a very basic .msi by following the WiX v3 Setup Project documentation, pretty much just the provided template, but no matter what i try, whenever i go to uninstall it via the Windows 10 `Apps & Features` interface, i keep getting this:

[image]

However, when i uninstall via `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` or by right-clicking and hitting Uninstall in the .msi's Context Menu, it uninstalls fine.

What am i missing here, should i be implementing something within the installer project to support the `Apps & Features` uninstall?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a pre-release of Windows you are testing? Are you logged in as normal user or as an administrator? (based on what you write almost certainly the latter, but let's be sure - you could be testing on virtuals). Are you in a corporate setting with controlled application estate and lots of group policies? What security software is running on your box? [See top of this answer for a "deployment mnemonic"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53677159/129130) (error check list / ideas list). Done a malware sweep? Try [Windows Defender offline modus](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17466)?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, logged in as administrator, home machine. Running AVG / Windows Defender. Ran both scans, completely clean.

Comment: OK, we need the source. You on github? Or if it is small, just dump in your question. You can leave out the bulk of the normal component parts if need be. Best with whole source.

Comment: No but I've thrown it in a pastebin for you, https://pastebin.com/c7YNmy7v

Comment: The only thing that stands out is the `InstallerVersion="300"` in the Package element. Where is this coming from? Did you follow a tutorial somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty much just the sample from here http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/add_a_file.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190874/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-spark).

Comment: Please see a couple of more comments in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***AVG Anti Virus***: In this case it was **`AVG anti virus`**. Uninstalling this product made the uninstall run correctly when
>   invoked from the new settings GUI in Windows 10.

***Blocking***: Errors like these often mean something is blocking the uninstall. Please disable or uninstall any anti-virus and / or security software and try again.

***General Check List***: Please check this answer for a "deployment check list" or "mnemonic" to debug similar problems: [Deployment Mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673451/wix-minimal-ui-doesnt-show-up/53677159#53677159) (mid-page). Also see comments above. Sweep for malware with [Windows Defender Offline](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17466).

- ***Microsoft Tips***: [Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2669244/windows-cannot-access-the-specified-device-path-or-file-error-when-you)...
- ***Make Log File***: To debug, always make an MSI log file:

  - [FireGiant: MSI log "how-to"](https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912407-Create-a-log-file-)
  - [Installsite: MSI log "how-to"](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm)

> ***Exact Error Message***: "*Error: Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item*"

Comment: [Similar problem](https://superuser.com/questions/1236536/cannot-uninstall-application-in-windows-10).