# Visual Studio MSI Installer: Asp.net Core as a Window Service

Tags: asp.net-core, service, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to create a MSI installer for asp.net core as a
windows service.

I was successful in creating the window service which host asp.net core application by using below links

1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.2

2)https://dzone.com/articles/running-aspnet-core-application-as-windows-service

But I want to create a MSI file(Visual Studio Installer) which will be installed by end user.
I will not be able to use third party installer i.e. Wix,Advance Installer etc.

Can anybody guide/help me how will I create a MSI file when installed it will automatically start the window service
or I am looking in wrong direction?

Comment: Adding only the main project dll's will do the trick.I was trying add all the dll at once which is the main cause of the issue.Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***WiX***: Visual Studio Installer projects have many limitations, you really should try WiX - which is free - or another commercial tool. [See list of major tools here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840). There are links in that overview to a list of Visual Studio Installer project limitations.

- [How to get started with WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130)

  - [Step-by-step minimal WiX project in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970743/wix-installer-msi-not-installing-the-winform-app-created-with-visual-studio-2017/47972615#47972615).
  - [How to install WiX service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53078696/how-to-create-install-for-window-service-in-visual-studio/53104548#53104548)
  - [How to use .NET custom actions - step-by-step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384739/129130)
- [How to get started with Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/)

  - Old, but written by MSI-expert **Phil Wilson** who also wrote [The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781590592977).