# WIX cannot find app.exe in x86/x64 output directory

Tags: wix, wix3.11

I have a C# application which its build targets are x86 or x64. The build output is (for example) `ProjectDir/bin/x86|x64/Debug|Release/*`

In my `*.wxs` file I have defined thr following variable

`<?define AppTargetPath = "$(var.MyApp.TargetPath)" ?>`

Which points to `ProjectDir/bin/Debug|Release/app.exe`

If I build the installer, it fails because it does not find my app exe

`<File Id="AppExe" Source="$(var.AppTargetPath)" KeyPath="yes"/>`

If I look on **Using Project References and Variables** site (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html) I cannot find another variable.

Comment: Added a couple of links that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved it by putting together the entire path on top of my wxs file:

```
<?define AppTargetFileName = "$(var.myApp.TargetFileName)" ?>

<?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
  <?define AppTargetPath = "$(var.myApp.ProjectDir)\bin\x64\$(var.myApp.Configuration)\$(var.AppTargetFileName)" ?>
<?elseif  $(var.Platform) = x86 ?>
  <?define AppTargetPath = "$(var.myApp.ProjectDir)\bin\x86\$(var.myApp.Configuration)\$(var.AppTargetFileName)" ?>
<?else ?>
  <?define AppTargetPath = "$(var.myApp.TargetPath)" ?>
<?endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

1. Comment out your existing define.
2. Add the project building the EXE and your WiX project to the same solution.
3. Add a reference from the WiX project to the EXE / Binary project.
4. Try this markup (replace project name **`"TestConsoleApplication"`** with yours):

   ```
   <Fragment>
     <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component>
       <File Source="$(var.TestConsoleApplication.TargetPath)" />
      </Component>
     </ComponentGroup>
   </Fragment>
   ```
5. Rebuild All.
6. Toggle Release and Debug builds, then Rebuild All again.

---

Links:

- ***Summary***: [**My WiX Quick Start Tips**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).
- ***Basic WiX Project***: [Step-by-step, Hello WiX project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972615/129130).
- ***Real-World Sample***: [Real-World Example: WiX/MSI Application Installer](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can you add the exe to the wix project? I can only reference the whole project. I don't know the exact path of my app, because of its different output path. But I like your "real world example" from your website!! 

Comment: The Real-World Example is from Helge Klein. I didn't think you needed to use defines for the paths like you do, you should be able to rely on auto-magic, but if the defines work that's great.